# Kubernetes Autoscaler missing node

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I’m having an issue with what I believe to be the k8s the autoscaler.

The autoscaler launched a new cluster after a recent deploy (and I can see that instance on EC2, where our k8s deployment’s hosted), but it doesn’t show up when I do kubectl get nodes.

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                             STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-172-20-110-212.ec2.internal   Ready     master    322d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-129-59.ec2.internal    Ready     master    322d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-153-170.ec2.internal   Ready     <none>    322d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-160-119.ec2.internal   Ready     master    322d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-162-94.ec2.internal    Ready     <none>    316d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-166-194.ec2.internal   Ready     <none>    322d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-79-1.ec2.internal      Ready     <none>    112d      v1.5.1
ip-172-20-92-163.ec2.internal    Ready     <none>    322d      v1.5.1
```

Further, a kube-proxy pod that matches this “missing” node’s IP does show up, but is killed and relaunched every 30 seconds.

```
kubectl get pods
kube-proxy-ip-172-20-181-122.ec2.internal                1/1       Running   0          17s
```

Comment: it would be good to share more details about node which is relaunching every 30 sec. May be `k describe node <nodename>` - without this data it is almost impossible to tell conclusively what might be wrong!

Comment: It's not the node that's relaunching but the pod. The node's missing from kubectl get nodes all together. The describe pod on the problematic pod doesn't yield any interesting information and there's no logged events before it's killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually deleting the EC2 instance. The autoscaler immediately relaunched a new instance and everything worked fine after.